# System of equations in $\mathbb{F}_p$

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic

I have:$$\begin{matrix}X&+&Y&+&Z&=&3,\\& &Y&+&Z&=&2,\\&-&Y&+&Z&=&0.\end{matrix}$$

Let furthermore $p$ be prime. How can I solve this system with respect to $\mathbb{F}_p$?

Comment: How would you have solved the system if you were in the field $\Bbb R$?

Comment: I get $X=Y=Z=1$ by adding line 2 to line 3.

Comment: Indeed and where did you use that the field was $\Bbb R$ in that case?

Comment: Didn't really use it.

Comment: I think you might've used the fact that $2Z = 2 \implies Z = 1$. That is not true in $\Bbb F_2$. However, apart from that, the usual method goes through in $\Bbb F_p$ for any prime $p \neq 2$. Thus, you only need to solve for $\Bbb F_2$ separately.

Comment: Ah, that makes so much sense! Thank you.

Comment: the solution set is given by the union of the solutions for $p\neq 2$ and $p=2$, right? And for $p=2$, we can use the analogous argumentation.

Comment: I don't think you should talk about a solution set like that. It makes sense to talk about the solution set for a fixed $p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from the comments. If we are not in a field of characteristic $2$, we can solve the system of linear equations in the usual manner and get $X = Y = Z = 1$ as the unique solution.

Thus, that is the solution in any $\Bbb F_p$ if $p > 2$.

---

For the case $p = 2$, we see that the equations become
\begin{align}
X + Y + Z &= 1,\\
Y + Z &= 0,\\
Y + Z &= 0.
\end{align}

(Recall that $Y = -Y$ in char $2$.)

Now we see that we actually have a redundancy in the system. (If you're familiar with linear algebra, we see that the coefficients matrix is not full rank and thus, we won't get a unique solution.)

Substituting $Y+Z = 0$ in the first equation gives us that $X = 1$. Thus, we are only left with $Y + Z = 0$ which has two solutions. Thus, the complete set of solutions is

$$(X, Y, Z) \in \{(1, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0)\}.$$

Answer (score 0):

In the first equation, replace $Y+Z$ with $2$ (by the 2nd equation). You get $X=1$. Add the 2nd and the third equation side-by-side, you get $2Z=2$. Now $if p\neq 2$ this yields $Z=1$ and then $Y=1$. Otherwise, if $p=2$, you have two solutions for $Y,Z$: either $Y=Z=1$ or $Z=Y=0$.